# Javascript sin function issue

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I have a problem with `Math.sin`. I thought it would output the sinus of the given integer. So I tried `Math.sin(30)` and my output was [`-0.9880316240928618`](http://jsfiddle.net/eqgbY/) and then I checked with my calculator and it was 0.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Parameters are assumed to be in radians, not degrees.

Try

```
Math.sin(Math.PI * (30/180));
```

A comment below notes that pre-computing the ratio π/180 is a good idea. One could add a companion to `Math.sin` that works on degrees this way:

```
Math.dsin = function() {
  var piRatio = Math.PI / 180;
  return function dsin(degrees) {
    return Math.sin(degrees * piRatio);
  };
}();
```

(Some people don't like extending built-in objects, but since one doesn't instantiate Math instances — at least, I don't — this doesn't seem terribly offensive.)

Comment: +1, precalculating `Math.PI / 180` has proven itself to be a great performance boost if used often.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, though I don't think I've ever used the trig functions in JavaScript other than for fun :-)

Comment: I was looking at it from a game perspective; I was able to obtain one extra frame per second from precalculating so I'd really recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.sin` works in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), I guess your calculator is in degrees.

Answer (score 3):

As was said above, Math.sin() requires the use of radians as input. To convert degrees to radians, use:

```
Radians = (Degrees * (Math.PI/180))
```

Answer (score 1):

Math.sin accepts values in radians, while your calculator is set to degrees.